# XSLT sorted node processing

Tags: xslt

Context node:

```
<a>
        <c refid="1" />
        <c refid="2" />
        <c refid="3" />
        <c refid="4" />
        <c refid="5" />
</a>
```

It gets the nodes referred to above, using a proprietary command:

```
<xsl:for-each select="get-a(@refid)">

<a id="1">
    <f att1="C"/>
    <f att2="I"/>
</a>
<a id="2">
    <f att1="C"/>
    <f att2="I"/>
</a>
<a id="3">
    <!--doesn't have f att1-->
    <f att2="I"/>
</a>
<a id="4">
    <f att1="R"/>
    <f att2="S"/>
</a>
<a id="5">
    <f att1="G"/>
    <f att2="I"/>
</a>
```

At present, I have it call a template within a for-each, but that will only do each  node separately, obviously.
But it must process them first based on the att2 value (these are set values, always I or S, so no problem), and then within that, based on att1 value to produce something like below, the first P node being the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0">
  
  <!--xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/-->
  
  <!-- This takes the first asset (betting that it's correct...) and uses it to establish the parameters below -->
  <xsl:variable name="rootSourceAssetXml">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/asset[1]"/>
    <!--xsl:copy-of select="./asset"/-->
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="xml">
      <O>
        <xsl:for-each select="$rootSourceAssetXml/asset/child_asset_rel[@key='user.']">
          <xsl:sort select="cs:get-asset(@child_asset)/f/@att2" order="ascending" data-type="text"/>
          <xsl:sort select="cs:get-asset(@child_asset)/f/@att1" order="descending" data-type="text"/>

          <xsl:variable name="getChapter">
            <xsl:variable name="getChapterXML" select="cs:get-asset(@child_asset)"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$getChapterXML">
              <xsl:if test="$getChapterXML/f/@att2='ebook'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$getChapterXML"/>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:variable>

          <xsl:call-template name="Group">
            <xsl:with-param name="thingGroup" select="$getChapter"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="resourceTypeWeb" select="'EBook'"/>
          </xsl:call-template>

          <xsl:variable name="getChapter">
             <xsl:variable name="getChapterXML" select="cs:get-asset(@child_asset)"/>
               <xsl:for-each select="$getChapterXML">
                 <xsl:if test="$getChapterXML/f att2='instructor'">
                   <xsl:copy-of select="$getChapterXML"/>
                 </xsl:if>
               </xsl:for-each>
             </xsl:variable>

             <xsl:call-template name="Group">
               <xsl:with-param name="thingGroup" select="$getChapter"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="resourceTypeWeb" select="'Instructor'"/>
             </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
      </O>
    </xsl:variable> <!-- Closes xml variable block -->
    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Group">
    <xsl:param name="thingGroup"/>
    <xsl:param name="resourceTypeWeb"/>

    <xsl:variable name="eachAsset">
      <xsl:for-each select="$thingGroup">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$thingGroup/asset"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="productResourceDescriptionGroupWeb" select="$eachAsset/asset/asset_feature[@feature='XXX:product-resource-description-group-web']/@value_string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="productResourceDescriptionDetailWeb" select="$eachAsset/asset/asset_feature[@feature='XXX:product-resource-description-detail-web']/@value_string"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="$eachAsset/asset">
    
    <P>
      <xsl:attribute name="e"><xsl:value-of select="$resourceTypeWeb"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="d"><xsl:value-of select="$productResourceDescriptionGroupWeb"/></xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:call-template name="Detail">
          <xsl:with-param name="resourceTypeWeb" select="$resourceTypeWeb"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="topAssetTypeName" select="$topAssetTypeName"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="thing" select="$eachAsset"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="productResourceDescriptionDetailWeb" select="$productResourceDescriptionDetailWeb"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </P>
    
    </xsl:for-each>
    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Should produce this:

```
<O>
    <P d="C" e="I"> <!-- This C is not a set value but a string, and it could be anything. Once the nodes with the same attribute are isolated, it is fine to grab the att value from node in position 1-->
        <id1>
            <!-- other info via call template; this works -->
        </id1>
        <id2>
            <!-- other info via call template; this works -->
        </id2>
    </P>
    <P  d="NULL" e="I">
        <id3>
            <!-- other info via call template; this works -->
        </id3>
    </P>
    <P  d="G" e="I">
        <id5>
            <!-- other info via call template; this works -->
        </id5>
    </P>
    <P  d="R" e="S">
        <id4>
            <!-- other info via call template; this works -->
        </id4>
    </P>
</O>
```

I have tried for-each-group calling a different template, and for-each with a sort for the value of att1, and other methods with no success.
This gives the right order, but I cannot bring nodes with same C value together:

```
<xsl:sort select="a/f/@att2"/>
<xsl:sort select="a/f/@att1"/>
```

The logic should be

```
for each <a> with same att2 value
  for each <a> with same att1 value
    output a single P with d=att1 value
    then process nodes with same att1
```

I know XSLT can't "loop" the way I'm used to with Perl, but I feel there is some way to do this by grouping or sorting, I just can't find the right combination. I keep getting so close, but then can't complete it.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: To help we need a [mcve] (emphasis on *minimal*) that includes original full XML and full (not snippets) XSLT. Please also post desired full XML. Redact as needed and provide working small samples if data and code are large.

Comment: The logic you describe should be easy to accomplish using two nested `xsl:for-each-group` instructions, with no need for sorting.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't do as you ask in the first place precisely because the existing code is NOT minimal, and the existing XSLT is so far off base I don't see how it would be helpful, but I gave it my best shot again, having pared it down. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is (still) very confusing. Consider the following **simplified** example:

**Input XML**

```
<root>
    <a id="1">
        <f att1="C"/>
        <f att2="I"/>
    </a>
    <a id="2">
        <f att1="C"/>
        <f att2="I"/>
    </a>
    <a id="3">
        <!--doesn't have f att1-->
        <f att2="I"/>
    </a>
    <a id="4">
        <f att1="R"/>
        <f att2="S"/>
    </a>
    <a id="5">
        <f att1="G"/>
        <f att2="I"/>
    </a>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="a" group-by="f/@att2">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="if (f/@att1) then f/@att1 else 'NULL'">
                <P d="{current-grouping-key()}" e="{f/@att2}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <abc id="{@id}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each> 
                </P>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <P d="C" e="I">
      <abc id="1"/>
      <abc id="2"/>
   </P>
   <P d="NULL" e="I">
      <abc id="3"/>
   </P>
   <P d="G" e="I">
      <abc id="5"/>
   </P>
   <P d="R" e="S">
      <abc id="4"/>
   </P>
</root>
```

This shows how to implement your stated logic:

```
for each <a> with same att2 value
  for each <a> with same att1 value
    output a single P with d=att1 value
    then process nodes with same att1
```

and nothing else.

Comment: Michael, crown yourself the king of solving "(still) very confusing" questions because you guided me in the right direction! The trouble was that the first for-each was unnecessary, causing it to execute too early on individual nodes. Once I gathered the a nodes as a single variable to mimic your example, instead of cycling through them, it worked.
Thank you very, very much indeed.